# Desktop-Streaming(Live Desktop & Audio Streaming to the browser with WebRTC) Error

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, live-streaming, uv4l

I wanted to load the xscreen driver. so I opened a terminal and typed the following commands:

```
$uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=5678'
```

This is the normal result:

```
raspberrypi ~ $ uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framerate 10 --server-option '--port=9000'

[core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from built-in drivers...
[core] Driver 'xscreen' not found
[core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from external plug-in's...
[driver] Opening display: :0
[driver] Display open, screen 0: 640x480, depth: 24, bpp: 32, big endian: false
[driver] Specified capturing rectangle: (xorigin 0, yorigin 0, width 640, height 480)
[core] Device detected!
[core] Trying to load the the Streaming Server plug-in...
[server] HTTP Streaming & WebRTC Signalling Server v1.1.18 built on Apr 22 2015
[core] Streaming Server loaded!
[core] Cannot create /dev/video0 because file already exists
[core] Registering device node /dev/video1
[server] Web Streaming Server listening on port 9000
```

But I got this message:

```
 $ uv4l --driver xscreen --auto-video_nr --display :0 --framee 10 --server-option '--port=5678'

<notice> [core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from built-in drivers...
<warning> [core] Driver 'xscreen' not found
<notice> [core] Trying driver 'xscreen' from external plug-in's...
<warning> [core] /usr/lib/uv4l/libxscreen.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost11ththread5hiden9sleep_forERK8timespec
<alert> [core] No device detected
```

What is my problem?
Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

update uv4l to the latest version, that will fix your specific problem, but consider using the raspidisp driver instead, as it is able to capture whatever you see on the screen, not just the x screen, and is much more faster, you can also optionally control your screen like vnc with the pc keyboard or smartphone